# Linq To Entities

Tags: model-view-controller, linq-to-entities

This has probably been answer already but I am trying to return the primary key after inserting a record to the database.  Does anyone know how this is accomplish after the record has been created?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The primary key will be set on the entity as soon as its saved.